# is there a way to groupby bulks using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame of different time series of different Trials of an experiment. the data contains columns of a vehicle's acceleration state. the states are -1 for deceleration, 0 for brake, 1 for acceleration.

I want to make a summary of every -1,0,1, and a need a way to group all the adjacent 1's while disregarding the other 1's. and the same for 0 and -1.

for example:
this is what I have:

| X axis acceleration | X axis state |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0.87 | 1 |
| 0.88 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |
| -0.28 | -1 |
| -0.27 | -1 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0.46 | 1 |
| 0.23 | 1 |

This what I want to get:

| mean X axis acceleration | X axis state | event number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0.875 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 0 | 3 |
| -0.275 | -1 | 4 |
| 0 | 0 | 5 |
| 0.345 | 1 | 6 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create groups by consecutive values of column `X axis state` and aggregate `mean`, last change order of columns by `list`:

```
g = df['X axis state'].ne(df['X axis state'].shift()).cumsum().rename('event number')

df = df.groupby([g, 'X axis state'])['X axis acceleration'].mean().reset_index()
df = df[['X axis acceleration','X axis state','event number']]

print (df)
   X axis acceleration  X axis state  event number
0                0.000             0             1
1                0.875             1             2
2                0.000             0             3
3               -0.275            -1             4
4                0.000             0             5
5                0.345             1             6
```

EDIT: If compare by shifted values get `True`s if values are changed:

```
print (df['X axis state'].ne(df['X axis state'].shift()))
0      True
1     False
2     False
3      True
4     False
5      True
6      True
7     False
8      True
9     False
10     True
11    False
Name: X axis state, dtype: bool
```

So if add cunmulative sum get groups:

```
print (df['X axis state'].ne(df['X axis state'].shift()).cumsum().rename('event number'))
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     3
6     4
7     4
8     5
9     5
10    6
11    6
Name: event number, dtype: int32
```

Comment: ohh thats great!, is there any chance you can describe what the first row does?

Comment: @MichaelFleicherTal - Added to answer.